# Some way to reset formatting when ENTER is pushed in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

When I do some special formatting when writing text (such as bolding or italics) it carries over to the next line when I push ENTER automatically. Is there any way to set it so that when ENTER is pushed the formatting resets back to default?

Comment: sort of like if you push ctrl+space how it resets - do that ctrl+space combo every time the enter key is pushed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple style called "Bold" and "Italics" with the correct formatting and use that instead of using bold and italics from the toolbar.

Under the style dialog you can set "Next Paragraph Style" to "Normal" which will reset formatting back to normal when you move to the next paragraph (press enter).